# Implementing pymemcache from python to rust

Tags: python, rust, memcached

I am migrating a project from python to rust, more specifically right now a file which uses the pymemchace library to call the set and get methods.
In order to set and get the cache a class was created, something like this:

```
   class Example:
     def __init__(self):
        # Create connection with to memcached server
     def set_cache(self, ... ):
        # Set cache
     def get_cache(self, ... ):
        # Get cache
   Instance = Example()
```

I know the OOP concepts like classes are implemented a differently on Rust compared to python.
How do you guys think I should approach this ? Build a struct and implement a method using the memcache crate or build a trait and call it as I needed ?

Edit[7/11/2022]:
After reading the comments this is the first model I have for the implementation of the memecache main methods:
rust
extern crate memcache;

```
use memcache::{Client, MemcacheError};

pub struct CacheManager {
    client: memcache::Client,
}

impl CacheManager {
    pub fn __ini__() -> Self {
        CacheManager {
            client: memcache::Client::connect("memcache://localhost:11211").unwrap(),
        }
    }
    pub fn set_cache(&self, key: &str, val: &str, expire: u32) -> bool {
        self.client.set(key, val, expire).unwrap();
        self.client.replace(" ", "", 100000000).unwrap();
        true
    }
    pub fn get_cache(&self, key: &str) -> Result<Option<String>, MemcacheError> {
        self.client.replace(" ", "", 100000000).unwrap();
        self.client.get(key)
    }
    pub fn get_or_set(self, key: &str, val: &str) -> bool {
        //If status cache already exist and value is the same then do nothing else set it
        let cache_val = self.get_cache(key);
        match cache_val.unwrap() {
            Some(i) => {
                if (i.parse::<i32>().unwrap() - val.parse::<i32>().unwrap()) < 1 {
                    true
                } else {
                    false
                }
            }
            None => {
                self.set_cache(key, val, 86400);
                false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What do you guys think ?

I will build some testing mod to try it out now.

Comment: Do you already have attempts? If yes, would you mind showing them?

Comment: From a first glance, it does sound like the `memcache` crate is what you want to use. Everything else is hard to say because it very much lacks context.

Comment: In Rust it's usually useful to think separately of the data, and of the logic that handles that data. Try gathering all the data that your `Example` class needs, and produce a struct out of it. Then, implement all the logic in an `impl` block. That's a very basic how-to if you have no idea where to start to translate from an OOP language to Rust. Once you have something like that, as @Finomnis said, you can show to us so that we can help you polishing it.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, once I have something built I will show it here :)